# text_field_tag doesn't show any field in my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is my view file

```
<%= form_tag results_path, class: "form-inline", :method => :get do %>
  <div class="input-group input-group-lg" >
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <%= link_to "clear", results_path, class: "btn btn-default" %>
    </div>
    <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], class: "form-control", id: "result_search", autocomplete: "on" %>
    <div class=input-group-btn">
      <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<%end%>
```

But I can see only clear button. Both text field and submit button are not displayed and when I hover around I see a disable symbol. Can anyone tell me where I am doing this wrong?

Comment: You missed " here in this line `<div class=input-group-btn">`.

Comment: are you using that text field as a autocomplete ?
change autocomplete value to off, then try.